# Given series of integers, provide the kth largest number

Tags: c++

Please help me in finding out what's wrong with my algo2() function.
The process for the algorithm 2 are the following:

- Read N Numbers into a vector
- Sort the vector elements in decreasing order
- Each remaining element is read one by one
- As a new element arrives, it is ignored if it is smaller than the kth element in the vector
- Else, it will be place in its correct spot in the array bumping one element out of the vector
- At the end, the element in the kth position will be printed

I've tried all I could; but every time I execute the algo2() function it simply stops executing. Your help would be very appreciated. Thank you.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    vector<int> input()
    {
        vector<int> nums;
        int input;

        cout << "Please enter some integers (type 12345 to end):\n";
        do 
        {
            cin >> input;
            nums.push_back(input);
        }
        while(input!=12345);
        nums.pop_back(); //omits terminator value from the vector

        return nums;
    }

    vector<int> sorter(vector<int> nums,int ilan)
    {
        int index,ctr;
        for(ctr=1;ctr<=pow((ilan-1),2);ctr++)
        {
            for(index=1;index<ilan;index++)
            {
                if(nums[index]>nums[index-1])
                {
                    nums[index]+=nums[index-1];
                    nums[index-1]=nums[index]-nums[index-1];
                    nums[index]-=nums[index-1];
                }
            }
        }
        return nums;
    }

    void cardinal(int k)
    {
        if(k==11||k==12||k==13)
            cout << "th";
        else
        {
            while(k>10)
            {
                k=k%10;
            }
            switch(k)
            {
                case 1: {cout << "st"; break;}
                case 2: {cout << "nd"; break;}
                case 3: {cout << "rd"; break;}
                default: cout << "th";
            }
        }
    }

    void output(vector<int> nums,int k)
    {
        cout << "The " << k;
        cardinal(k);
        cout << " largest number is " << nums[k-1];
    }

    void algo2(vector<int> nums,int k)
    {
        int index;
        int cursor;
        nums = sorter(nums,k);
        for(cursor=k;cursor+1<nums.size();)
        {
            if(nums[k-1]<nums[cursor])
            {
                for(index=0;index<(k-1);index++)
                {
                    if(nums[cursor]>nums[index])
                    {
                        nums.insert(nums.begin()+index,nums[cursor]);
                        if(k+2==nums.size())
                            nums.erase(nums.begin()+k+1);
                        else
                            nums.erase(nums.begin()+k,nums.begin()+k+1);
                        break;
                    }   
                }
            }
            else
            {
                nums.erase(nums.begin()+cursor);
                break;
            }
        }
        output(nums,k);
    }

    int main()
    {
        vector<int> nums;
        int choice=0, k=0;

        cout << "Type the algorithm number you'll use (1 or 2): ";
        cin >> choice;
        cout << "Input k: ";
        cin >> k;

        //Algorithm 1
        if(choice==1)
        {
            nums = input();
            nums = sorter(nums,nums.size());
            output(nums,k);
        }
        //Algorithm 2
        else if(choice==2)
        {
            nums = input();
            algo2(nums,k);
        }

        cout << endl << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Where does it "stop executing"? What did you do already to find the bug?

Comment: You do know that there is a built-in sort function, right?http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Comment: I can't fine the place where you update the variable `cursor`. As is, it seems to be fixed at the index `k`.

Comment: @Christian Severin, it stops executing when I finished input 12345 as my terminator.

Comment: @Aravind, I know there's a built-in function of sort but my professor says that we should manually sort it using looping structures.

Comment: Why don't you put debug statements like cout in algo2 and test if it was ever called?

Comment: @NykerMatthewKing: Does it *stop*, or does it *run forever?* There's a difference between the two (and civen the noted non-updating of `cursor`, I strongly suspect the second).

Comment: @celtschk, at first, I thought I should update it as I initially put a cursor++ there in the for loop parameter but since my vector is shrinking as a new element is read, I thought that there would be no need for an incrementation since the only value I compare with my k variable is the current cursor element.

Comment: @NykerMatthewKing:It's runs on my computer, though the output is wrong.

Comment: @Aravind, I've alreadyy debug those statements, but it seems that there is something wrong with the if condition of if(nums[cursor]>nums[index]) because the statements there (in the if part) doesn't execute

Comment: @Aravind, only the output() function runs in my machine. The algo2() function doesn't. Could you tell me what could be the reason why the output is wrong? Thank you.

Comment: But if the `output` function runs, the program doesn't stop somewhere, but it obviously runs to end; it just doesn't do what you intended it to do (I assume the `system("pause") statement also is executed?).

Comment: @celtschk, in my screen, I had waited for several minutes but still, after entering 12345, I could view no outputs. Even the sentence "Press any key to continue...", which I'm anticipating, doesn't appear. Although if I go through the output function, it perfectly went well.

Comment: better use std::multiset in c++. that can help you !

Comment: So the program did *not* stop, but run forever (because otherwise, what would you have waited for?).

Comment: @celtschk, what do you think could be the probable solution to my problem?

Comment: @ to all: Thank you very much for your time and effort. I really do appreciate your help a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the working code.You need to erase the element you are considering now.

Quick points:
Your sort works fine, but I changed it to the way I'm comfortable with.Ignore the changes in the sorter function.
Concentrate on the algo2 function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> input()
{
    vector<int> nums;
    int input;

    cout << "Please enter some integers (type 12345 to end):\n";
    do 
    {
        cin >> input;
        nums.push_back(input);
    }
    while(input!=12345);
    nums.pop_back(); //omits terminator value from the vector

    return nums;
}

vector<int> sorter(vector<int> nums,int ilan)
{
    int index,ctr;
    for(ctr=0;ctr<ilan;ctr++)
    {
        for(index=ctr+1;index<ilan;index++)
        {
            if(nums[index]>nums[index-1])
            {
                nums[index]+=nums[index-1];
                nums[index-1]=nums[index]-nums[index-1];
                nums[index]-=nums[index-1];
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    for(int i=0;i<ilan;i++)
     cout<<nums[i]<<" ";
    getch(); 
    return nums;
}

void cardinal(int k)
{
    if(k==11||k==12||k==13)
        cout << "th";
    else
    {
        while(k>10)
        {
            k=k%10;
        }
        switch(k)
        {
            case 1: {cout << "st"; break;}
            case 2: {cout << "nd"; break;}
            case 3: {cout << "rd"; break;}
            default: cout << "th";
        }
    }
}

void output(vector<int> nums,int k)
{
    cout << "The " << k;
    cardinal(k);
    cout << " largest number is " << nums[k-1];
}

void algo2(vector<int> nums,int k)
{
    int index;
    int cursor;
    nums = sorter(nums,k);
    while(k<nums.size())
    {
        int t=nums[k];
        nums.erase(nums.begin()+k);                
        if(nums[k-1]<t)
        {
            for(index=0;index<=(k-1);index++)
            {
                if(t>nums[index])
                {
                    nums.insert(nums.begin()+index,t);
                    nums.erase(nums.begin()+k);
                    break;
                }   
            }
        }
    }
    output(nums,k);
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> nums;
    int choice=0, k=0;

    cout << "Type the algorithm number you'll use (1 or 2): ";
    cin >> choice;
    cout << "Input k: ";
    cin >> k;

    //Algorithm 1
    if(choice==1)
    {
        nums = input();
        nums = sorter(nums,nums.size());
        output(nums,k);
    }
    //Algorithm 2
    else if(choice==2)
    {
        nums = input();
        algo2(nums,k);
    }

    cout << endl << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in the sorter function, why is there the need to print the iterated contents (until k) of the vector? The modification you've made in the algo2() function, if sorter function's output were to be disregarded, I think, with all due respect, there's something wrong in the output of the modified program. I need the kth largest number in the series entered by the user. For example, if I input numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 and, 5 and my k is equal to 2, it should give me the result of the element: 4.

Comment: Yes there, I'm on fixing it, sorry.Please wait.

Comment: I have updated the code.Please ask if you have more questions.

Comment: great!!! Really great! It's working. I could only repay you through a word of thanks. You've saved my day. I have been working on this since the last 5 hours and I'm stuck. Thank you very much for your time and effort!

Comment: Why is it when the given integers are 6, 25, 3, 0, -9, 10, 8, 4, and 1; where k=5, it gives me the 5th largest number is 3? (which is supposed to be 4)

Comment: Oh my, fixed it.It seems you made a fundamental mistake here:
index=0;index<(k-1);index++, which should be, index=0;index<=(k-1);index++

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. My mind wouldn't just work perfectly unlike this morning. It's been drained a lot. Since I found out there was this error, I've been manually simulating the code since I've lost my trust in my debugging skills. It now works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: You modified my sorter function wherein the inner for loop's initialization should be index=1 rather than index=ctr+1. The rest of the code is logically correct. But if the initialization remains index=ctr+1 rather than index=1, if given 1,2,3,...,9, given k=5, it will print the number of 2 rather than the number of 5. Nevertheless, your modifications helped me a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've now found the problem:

If you found a larger element, you insert it in the vector at the appropriate place and then remove the smallest element from the first `k`, which is now at position `k`. So far, it's fine. However, you do *not* delete the element you just inserted at the beginning from the rest of the vector. Therefore in the next iteration it finds the *very same* element again. Since you also do that if the element *equals* the found element, the result is an endless loop.

Anyway, here's an algorithm which essentially does the same as yours after correction, but takes advantage of the standard library facilities (well, apart from taking advantage of the pre-made `nth_element` algorithm, of course :-)). One other change is that I added some error checking. What I didn't change is the fact that your algorithm does the output. Normally the algorithm should just return its findings and leave it to the caller what to do with it.

```
void algo2_improved(std::vector<int> num, int k)
{
  if (num.size() < k)
  {
    std::cout << "there are too few elements in the vector!\n";
    return;
  }

  std::sort(num.begin(), num.begin()+k, std::greater<int>());

  while (num.size() > k)
  {
    if (num[k] >= num[k-1])
      std::rotate(std::upper_bound(num.begin(),
                                   num_begin()+k,
                                   num[k],
                                   std::greater<int>()),
                  num.begin()+k,
                  num.begin()+k+1);
    num.erase(num.begin()+k);
  }
  output(num, k);
}
```

Comment: I see. So that's why. Thank you :)

Comment: @NykerKing: Note my edit to give improved code implementing the same algoritm.

Comment: `nth_element` is the way to go., +1 because of mentioning it

Comment: @NykerKing: It turned out my code was wrong. I've now fixed it.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed it earlier when the given integers are 6, 25, 3, 0, -9, 10, 8, 4, and 1; where k=5, it gives me the 5th largest number is -9. Now, it's functioning correctly. Thanks for the modification. I appreciate it a lot. :) This could be a bit greedy of me, but, could you explain the rotate function? :)

Comment: @NykerKing: Well, it does what the name says: It rotates a sequence of numbers. More exactly, it rotates it so that the element pointed to by the middle iterator comes first afterwards. So if you have the sequence `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8` and you do a `rotate(i2, i4, i7)` (where `in` is an iterator pointing to the nth element), you get the sequence `1 4 5 6 2 3 7 8`. BTW, also note that when called with `std::greater`, `upper_bound` actually returns the *lower* bound on a reverse-sorted sequence.

Comment: @celtschk, Yes. Thank you for that clear explanation. I've learned a lot from this forum. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is the best method to find the Kth largest number.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int partion(int arr[], int left, int right)
{
    int i = left;
    int j = right;
    int target = arr[i];

    while (i < j)
    {
        if (arr[j] > target)
            j--;
        arr[i] = arr[j];

        if (arr[i] <= target)
            i++;
        arr[j] = arr[i];
    }
    arr[j] = target;
    return j;
}


void quickSort(int arr[], int start, int end)
{
    if(start >= end)
        return;

    int pos = partion(arr, start, end);

    quickSort(arr, start, pos);
    quickSort(arr, pos+1, end);
}

int kth_element(int arr[], int start, int end, int k)
{
    int pos = partion(arr, start, end);
    if (pos == k)
        return arr[pos];
    else if (pos < k)
        kth_element(arr, pos + 1, end, k);
    else
        kth_element(arr, start, pos, k);
}
struct print
{
    void operator()(int a)
    {
        cout<<a<<" ";
    }
};
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);

    quickSort(arr, 0, len - 1);

    for_each(arr, arr + len, print());
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"k = 2:  "<<kth_element(arr, 0, len - 1, len - 2)<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Since his tast was probably not the sorting algorithm, the best method includes not a self-written quicksort, but the standard function `std::sort` which will almost certainly be more efficient by applying all the well-known improvements to the quicksort algorithm, and also taking a better pivot element (probably median-of-three).